# Preferred network available, but still prompted

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, macbook

Very frequently, when I wake my Macbook up, I'll be prompted to select a network, as "none of my preferred networks is available". Yet, my home network, very much a preferred network (I can see it in the list of preferred WiFi networks in Network Preferences), is right there in the list, and my computer won't connect unless I select it.

How can I get my computer to recognize my preferred network (which it is clearly aware of) and stop asking me to join it?

I'm running Mountain Lion v10.7.3 on a Macbook Air, and am happy to provide more information as needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my MacBook Air, but it was fixed after I disabled Bluetooth from System Preferences. Others have changed the Wi-Fi channel in their router's preferences. There's apparently some issue with interference between Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.

Related questions:

- [Macbook (unibody plastic) won't reconnect to wifi after setting up new router while other devices do just fine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37297/macbook-unibody-plastic-wont-reconnect-to-wifi-after-setting-up-new-router-wh)
- [Have to reconnect to WiFi every time computer goes to sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19156/have-to-reconnect-to-wifi-every-time-computer-goes-to-sleep)